# Keep div heights the same when image inside are different heights

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap page that has a row of DIVs and there is an image in each div. In the example below, the height of the first two DIV's will be the same as you resize the browser, but the 3rd div will have a different height as the image is only 50pixels high.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col1 col-md-4">
        <img src="image160x160.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="col2 col-md-4">
        <img src="image160x160.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="col3 col-md-4">
        <img src="image160x50.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I ensure that the DIVs always remain the same height no matter what resolution they are in?

Comment: Please add css style you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `row` as `flex-container` and set `align-items: stretch`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{ 
  margin:0;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.col {
  margin: 8px;
  border: 4px solid darkgoldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col1">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col col2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col col3">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x50"/> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: If you choose this method - I would recommend changing classnames from `row` and `col` to something else, since it may conflict with bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can put fix height on div and set height:100% on img

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  /*Ex*/
}

div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1 col-md-4">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160" />
  </div>

  <div class="col2 col-md-4">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x160" />
  </div>

  <div class="col3 col-md-4">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x50" />
  </div>
</div>
```